# Asp.net Mvc jquery ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, partial-views

I have links like following.

```
<a href="/Customer/_EditCustomer?CustomerId=2" class="customer_details">Deneme Müşteri 2</a>
<a href="/Customer/_EditCustomer?CustomerId=3" class="customer_details">Deneme Müşteri 2</a>
```

I want to use jquery ajax post like this:

```
$(".customer_details").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        complete: function () {

        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#customer_operations_container").html(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Hata!");
        }
    });   //end ajax
});
```

Or this:

```
$(".customer_details").click(function () {
    $("#customer_operations_container").load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

And Action Method

```
public ActionResult _EditCustomer(int CustomerId)
{
    // get customer from db by customer id.
    return PartialView(customer);
}
```

But I cant do what I wanted. When I click to link, PartialView does not load. It is opening as a new page without its parent. I tried prevent.Default but result is the same.

How can I load the partialView to into a div?

Note: If I use link like this `<a href="#">` it works.

Thanks.

Comment: you may want to try this: $(".customer_details").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); [rest of your code]

Comment: I tried it but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is with the actionresult, try with Content to see if that changes anything.

```
public ActionResult _EditCustomer(int CustomerId)
{
    // get customer from db by customer id.
    return Content(customer.ToString());
}
```

Try one of these...

```
$(".customer_details").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        //I think you want a GET here? Right?
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        complete: function () {

        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#customer_operations_container").html(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Hata!");
        }
    });   //end ajax
});
```

Or

```
$(".customer_details").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#customer_operations_container").load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Or

```
 $(".customer_details").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
          $("#customer_operations_container").html(data);
    });
});
```

If none of this works, check if there's any js errors

Comment: I tried all of them. But it does not work. I cant understand why.

Comment: Is there a successful connection to Jquery ?

Comment: try changing the a tag to a span/div :p

Comment: click function is not trigerred.

Comment: problem is jqgrid. Links are in jqgrid. I write "prevent.Default" in jqgrid loadComplete event and its work. Thanks a lot everybody.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you click on the link you already start navigation to it. So just use `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` from the `click` method to prevent the default behavior

```
$(".customer_details").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

Comment: It must work, I know. I debugged but no error or warning. It open partialView as a new page

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("href"),
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                complete: function () {

                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#customer_operations_container").html(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Hata!");
                }
            });   //end ajax
            return false;
```

The only thing you where missing is the prevention of A tag working. By returning `false` your custom event is called and the default event is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $(".customer_details").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Using `ready` event

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hdqDZ/